# Search multiple tables with no relation by special value with one query using linq to entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following linq queries:

```
var bas = new BaskoolEntities();
var radif = "0011395000505000821";
            var query = (from a in bas.ChekedList
                where a.Radifkolsal == radif
                from b in bas.PrioritedList
                where b.Radifkolsal == radif
                from c in bas.IssuedBills
                where c.Radifkolsal == radif
                select new
                {
                    a,
                    b,
                    c
                }).ToList();
```

I want find a field in 3 tables with no relations in database by one query using Linq to Entity in C#. I am new in Linq programing an googling it but found no result useful to me.
Can anyone give me a solution?
thanks in advance.

Comment: What is wrong with the query you posted ? Wrong results ? Not working ? Exception ? Do you have an SQL alternative of what you want to achieve, please post the expected results.

Comment: What you are currently doing is a `cross join`

Comment: it has no result in one query but if i use three query separately it works fine. I ha SQL databese.

Comment: So you want to join the three tables on field `Radifkolsal` where its value is  equal to `radif` and return all the columns of the three tables ?

Comment: Yes, but if it just return only Radifkolsal, it is better.

Comment: @kavir the value of `Radifkolsal` is already `0011395000505000821` . Are you trying to check if there is any matching result in the database only ? So you want true or false only from this operation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in your comments, you want to find if there is a result or not one of the tables at least, you can do something like this using `Any()`:

```
var radif = "0011395000505000821";
var found = (from a in bas.ChekedList
             where a.Radifkolsal == radif
             || bas.PrioritedList.Any(p => p.Radifkolsal == radif)
             || bas.IssuedBills.Any(i => i.Radifkolsal == radif)
             select a).Any();
```

if you used `var result = ..... select a.Radifkolsal` you would get the value `0011395000505000821` or null. Which is useless for me unless your goal is to find (Do i have a matching result or not) which is exactly what the above query does.

Comment: It doesn't give me the correct result and not found anything.

Comment: @kavir do you have records with `0011395000505000821` in the three tables ?

Comment: I have that record in two of them.

Comment: @kavir So what do you what ? Match it even if it is found in one of the tables  only ?

Comment: Yes, exactly it is that i want.

Comment: Yes it works but i want to know which table contain that field. Is it possible achieve that in this query?

Comment: How can I find that which table contain that field in this query?

Comment: @kavir Unfortunately you can't using this query. I think you need to do separate queries to get that info.

Comment: You mean that there is no way to do it in one query!!!.I don't have enough information about linq but should be another way. By the the way, thanks for your help.

Comment: @kavir Can you do that in pure SQL with one query ?

Comment: If there is now way in linq, maybe I should do it with SQL. Can you give me a solution?

Comment: @kavir I don't think it can be done in one query in SQL. That's why it can't be done in Linq (Which get translated in SQL). I'm asking you if you can do in yourself in SQL so that we can find a linq translation for it.

Comment: Ok, I will try it and let you now the result.